# Best way to organize API base URL for different environment in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

We have 3 environments `Dev, Stage and Prod` for our API. I have 3 targets and schemes for 3 environments setup in my Xcode which have different builds, code signing, profiles and plist.

How do I do the same for API base URL? right now I have all in 1 prefix file. Because it is 1 project so all 3 targets are using the same file and I have to change the comment out every time I build for different environment.

```
//DEV
#define SERVER_URL @"http://api.dev.com/api/"
//STAGE
#define SERVER_URL @"http://api.stage.com/api/"
//PROD
#define SERVER_URL @"http://api.prd.com/api/"
```

What is the best way to organize API base URL for different target environment in Xcode?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around and found a simple yet effective solution for me.

I put the `API base URL` as a value in the `plist` of each target with the key `@"ServerURL"`. Then on the singleton class interfacing with the API, I put this in the init

```
NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
serverURL = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"ServerURL"];
```

There I have the correct serverURL based on which target I'm building.

Comment: You can have more differences between targets (using certain frameworks or not, ...), which makes preprocessor macro's better to maintain than .plist values

Answer (score 1):

First, for anything as complicated as this, I strongly recommend using xcconfig files rather than the build pane for configuration. [This article](http://robnapier.net/build-system-1-build-panel) is fairly dated, but the information is still fairly accurate (minus some minor changes in the Xcode UI).

Using that technique, you can mix-in different xcconfig files for different build configurations (Dev, Stage, Prod). Within the correct xcconfig, you can use `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` to set any macros you need:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = SERVER_URL=@"http://api.dev.com/api/"
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of your targets, you could add a different preprocessor macro (located in the build settings of your targets). E.g. your Dev target defines `DEV=1`.

The `DEBUG` macro is one good example and should be existent for your debug configuration in each target. You have to specify your custom preprocessor macros for each configuration (Debug, Release, ...)

In your prefix header file you can now check with `#ifdef` or `#if defined`, which target you are currently building.

```
#if defined DEV
  #define SERVER_URL @"http://api.dev.com/api/"
#elif defined STAGE
  #define SERVER_URL @"http://api.stage.com/api/"
#elif defined PROD
  #define SERVER_URL @"http://api.prd.com/api/"
#endif
```

I think it should work like this but don't pin me down on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the base url to you info.plist like this $(BAE_URL)

```
// .xcconfig
BASE_URL = http:/$()/someurl.com


enum API {
    static let baseUrl = Bundle.infoPlistValue(forKey: "BASE_URL", 
        valueType: String.self)
}

extension Bundle {
    static func infoPlistValue<T>(forKey key: String, valueType: T.Type) -> 
    T? {
        guard let value = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: key) as? 
    T 
        else { return nil }
    return value
```