# How to load base url based on selected target

Tags: ios, swift

how can I load URL based on the selected targets for Xcode.

I got four environments for iPhone project.

```
1) Development [Base Url https://DemoDevelopmentURL.com/]
2) Testing (QA) [Base Url https://DemoTestURL.com/]
3) Staging (PreProduction) [Base Url https://DemoPreProductionURL.com/]
4) Production (Live) [Base Url https://DemoProductionURL.com/]
```

Based on selected target how do we can load related Base url

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571641/best-way-to-organize-api-base-url-for-different-environment-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

By checking target bundle id:

```
let baseUrl: String!

switch Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier{
case "Development bundle id":
    baseUrl = "https://DemoDevelopmentURL.com/"
case "Testing bundle id":
    baseUrl = "https://DemoTestURL.com/"
case "Staging bundle id":
    baseUrl = "https://DemoPreProductionURL.com/"
default:
    baseUrl = "https://DemoProductionURL.com/"
}
```

or put the base url on every target info.plist, then load it from the file:

```
 var baseUrl: String {
    guard let value = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "BaseURL") as? String else {
        print("Could not find BaseURL variable in info.plist")
        return "https://DemoProductionURL.com/"
    }
    return value
 }
```

Comment: Good suggestion. However, keep in mind that you cannot declare `baseUrl` as constant (`let`), it has to be variable (`var`) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do this by creating extra project configurations. This allows you to configure not only your base url, but other build settings on a per configuration (environment) basis. Additionally, you don't have the overhead of maintaining additional targets (although you can build with different bundle ids by setting a different **info.plist** per config).

[image]

Add custom compiler flags in your build settings…

[image]
select the appropriate config in the scheme settings…

[image]
then you can test as follows…

```
func baseUrl() -> URL {
    #if DEBUG
    return URL(string: "debug base url")
    #elseif TESTING
    return URL(string: "debug testing url")
    #elseif STAGING
    return URL(string: "debug staging url")
    #elseif PRODUCTION
    return URL(string: "debug production url")
    #endif
}
```